# Trying to use APP Script var dorss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('DOR Printers'); to open a new spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

`function getss() {`
```` var dorss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('DOR Printers'); ``` ````
  Logger.log(dorss);```

Get error: Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp. at getss(macros:31:30)

Comment: The ID is the portion of the URL after /d/ eg. `/d/1CmtwXZvlyfHfqVcKWjiXMGtTK0dQ1owUT4q4jaI/edit#gid=2132593893` The ID is `1CmtwXZvlyfHfqVcKWjiXMGtTK0dQ1owUT4q4jaI`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `openByUrl`. It requires the spreadsheet URL as parameter instead of the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

To open a spreadsheet with Apps Script you will need to use one of these three methods:

[OpenbyId(ID)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) : where the parameter to pass is the ID of the spreadsheet (which, when you acess your spreadsheet you can find it in your URL between `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/` and `/edit#gid=`

[OpenByUrl(URL)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl) : where the parameter to pass is simply the URL of your spreadsheet.

[Open(file)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openfile) : where the parameter to pass is the File object of the spreadsheet that you can obtain following the example of the documentation.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)